# How can I move CGRect with UITouches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I move CGRect with uitouches? If anyone has idea please explain.

```
if(areaSelected)
        return;
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Didnt understand ur question ... what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Shehbaz do want to draw line?

Comment: i want to move my a rectangle and this is myrect code CGRect cropRect= [myPath bounds];
 
  // Retina
  cropRect= CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x-10, cropRect.origin.y, cropRect.size.width*1.5, cropRect.size.height*1.5);

Comment: so u want to move your cropped image from x to y ..

Comment: yes,please help,and want to move image everywhere

Comment: try this....                                                        -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
// Get Touch location
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
// Set touch location's center to ImageView
imageView.center = touchLocation;
}         if you found solution just intimate me...

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per my understanding you need to move the cropped image to one place to other place so you need to code it in the touches stuff...

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    cloud.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Here cloud is the UIImageView you can make it as cropped image ....

```
 cloud.image=croppedImage;   //[you must assign this first...]
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: thanx spynet it really help me aloot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the frame of the rectangle:

```
[cropRect setFrame:CGRectMake(<new x coordinate>, <new y coordinate>, width, height)]
```